# NOT FOUND error on API built with .NET 6 and deployed through IIS

Tags: web, iis, hosting, .net-6.0

#### `Program.cs`

```cs
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using System.Reflection;
using WindowsProxy.Interfaces;
using WindowsProxy.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

//Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.Services.AddControllers();
//Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthUserService, AuthUserService>();
//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("cors",
        builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
});


//builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//{
//    //By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
//    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
//});

var app = builder.Build();

//Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("cors");

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

#### `web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WindowsProxy.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: d0c0a55a-a8fb-4ab1-b406-55db25ed63b0-->
```

I have tried multiple different configs, APP pool is defined using integrated 4.0 pipeline,
agent user does have full access to file directory. App pool identity is being used by agent account. I can get this to work just fine using swagger. Was having auth issues but seem to have resolved that. It looks like I am talking to the server correctly but the error indiciates a configuration issue.

When pinging from the browser directly I get:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

How do I find this API on the web?

Comment: try changing the AppPool setting from 'v4.0' to 'No Managed Code'.  Under Authentication on IIS site 'Enable Anonymous Authentication'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Still getting a Not found message back from the server. @ChinmayT

Comment: You can also try to choose .Net v4.5 and Classic.

Comment: I have also tried that @samwu. I have gotten it to communicate with my application once before with an integrated pipeline but i redeployed in order to clean the folder up and thats when it stopped working. I assume there is some issue with how IIS is supposed to read the dll.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.